# Application has stopped working using Android Studio, no errors detected in code

Tags: android

My app should have a button on the main page that navigates to the second page and on the second page, there is some edit text boxes and 2 buttons. Whenever i run the app, I can get to the main page but when I attempt to go to the second page the app stops working. I notice I get this response:

> Emulator: emulator: INFO: QtLogger.cpp:68: Critical: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'update' of undefined (qrc:/html/js/location-mock-web-channel.js:130, (null))

I'm not sure why is doing this. Do i need to update something or am i missing a crucial step in my code?
Please help :(.

**Main.java**

```
package com.example.hw2;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }
    public void onClick(View view) {
        startActivity(new Intent("com.example.hw2.SecondActivity"));
    }

}
```

**Second.java**

```
package com.example.hw2;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;


import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;

public class SecondActivity extends Activity {

    DBHandler myDb;
    EditText editName, editSName, editEmail, editMobile;
    Button btnAddContact,btnViewAll, btnReturn;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        myDb = new DBHandler(this);
        editName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_name);
        editSName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_sname);
        editEmail = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_email);
        editMobile = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_mobile);
        btnAddContact = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_add);
        btnViewAll = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_viewAll);
        btnReturn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_goback);
        AddData();
        ViewAll();
        Return();
    }

    public void AddData(){
        btnAddContact.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                boolean isInserted= myDb.insertData(editName.getText().toString(),editSName.getText().toString(),editEmail.getText().toString(),editMobile.getText().toString());
                if(isInserted)
                    Toast.makeText(SecondActivity.this, "Contact Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                else
                    Toast.makeText(SecondActivity.this, "Failed to Save", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }

    public void ViewAll(){
        btnViewAll.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                Cursor res = myDb.displayContacts();
                if(res.getCount()==0){
                    showMessage("Error", "No Contacts");
                    return;
                }
                StringBuffer buffer =new StringBuffer();
                while(res.moveToNext()){
                    buffer.append("ID:"+res.getString(0)+"\n");
                    buffer.append("Name :"+res.getString(1)+"\n");
                    buffer.append("Last Name:"+res.getString(2)+"\n");
                    buffer.append( "Mobile:"+res.getString(4)+"\n");
                    buffer.append("Email:"+res.getString(3)+"\n\n");
                }
                showMessage("Contact", buffer.toString());
            }
        });
    }
    public void Return(){
        btnReturn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                finish();
            }
        });
    }


    public void showMessage(String Title, String Contact){
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setCancelable(true);
        builder.setTitle(Title);
        builder.setMessage(Contact);
        builder.show();
    }

}
```

**DBhandler.java**

```
package com.example.hw2;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

public class DBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME="main.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME="CONTACT";
    public static final String COL_1="ID";
    public static final String COL_2="NAME";
    public static final String COL_3="SNAME";
    public static final String COL_4="EMAIL";
    public static final String COL_5="MOBILE";


    public DBHandler(Context context){
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    }

    public DBHandler(@Nullable Context context, @Nullable String name, @Nullable SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, name, factory, version);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("create table "+TABLE_NAME+"(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, NAME TEXT, SNAME TEXT, EMAIL VARCHAR(20), MOBILE INTEGER(12) )");

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public boolean insertData(String name, String sname,String email, String mobile) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL_2, name);
        contentValues.put(COL_3, sname);
        contentValues.put(COL_4, email);
        contentValues.put(COL_5, mobile);
        long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
        if (result == -1)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }

    public Cursor displayContacts() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from " + TABLE_NAME, null);
        return res;
    }
}
```

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Click the button to add a contact"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="Display second activity"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**second.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.hw2.SecondActivity">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        >
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="Name"
            android:id="@+id/editText_name"
            />

        <EditText
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:text="Last Name"
            android:id="@+id/editText_sname"
            />
        <EditText
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/editText_email"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:text="Email"


            />
        <EditText
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/editText_mobile"
            android:inputType="phone"
            android:text="Mobile"

            />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/button_add"
            android:text="Save"

            />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/button_viewAll"
            android:text="View All"

            />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/button_goback"
            android:text="Return"

            />

    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.hw2">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".SecondActivity">
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="com.example.hw2.SecondActivity" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Seems everyting okay. Please try to run on real device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are starting second activity wrong. Instead of

```
startActivity(new Intent("com.example.hw2.SecondActivity"));
```

change it to

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class));
```

Also, the layout attached in your Second activity is of first activity. This would cause `NullPointerException` when accessing the views in SecondActivity.

Change

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

to

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need two values to move pages, these are origin and destination
The origin is the page you are on and the destination of the page you are redirecting to

try it

```
startActivity(new Intent(this,SecondActivity.class));
```

this = activity or context origin page

Answer (score 0):

change

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

to

```
setContentView(R.layout.second);
```

In your second activity, You are trying to inflate wrong view.